# how to read text from excel file in python pandas?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, import

I am working on a excel file with large text data. 2 columns have lot of text data. Like descriptions, job duties.

When i import my file in python df=pd.read_excel("form1.xlsx"). It shows the columns with text data as NaN.

How do I import all the text in the columns ?
I want to do analysis on job title , description and job duties. Descriptions and Job Title are long text. I have over 150 rows.

Comment: You should give a short example of your data and your code so far that should make it easier to help you. The questions as it is now is hard to understand. please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the file from .xlsx to .CSV 
I had the same problem with text columns so i tried converting to CSV (Comma Delimited) and it worked. Not very helpful, but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dictionary of column names and datatypes to read_excel with the `dtype` keyword:

```
col_dict = {‘a’: str, ‘b’: int}
pd.read_excel("form1.xls", dtype=col_dict)
```